# Core Plot, It takes a long time to display a label on top of each bar column

Tags: label, core-plot

I'd like to display a label on top of each bar column with the delegate method:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot 
                  recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor]; 
    textStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"x" style:textStyle]
                           autorelease];
    return textLayer;
}
```

In case that it is my project that brings this problem, I directly insert this code snippet into the CPTTestAppBarChartController.m file in the CPTTestApp-iPhone project downloaded from
[here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=CorePlot_0.9.zip&can=2&q=).
But it still takes about 2 mins to display the labels. How can I make it display faster?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you plotting? If it's a lot (100's of points), you might want to only create labels for the visible points. Reload the data using the `-reloadDataInIndexRange:` method to load new labels when new data moves into the visible range.

You can also create the text style once and store it in a static local variable or an ivar instead of creating a new one for every label. That will save a little bit of time if you have a lot of labels.

P.S. Be sure to use `[CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle]` instead of `[CPTTextStyle textStyle]` to create the text style.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, it didn't work for me. Maybe it got nothing to  do with how much data I'm plotting.     My CPTGraphHostingView is the subview of UIScrollView. And you know what, if I scroll the scrollView a little bit, the text labels will appear at once! That's weird...

Comment: So... I added [self.myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(35.0f, 0.0f) animated:YES] to the viewDidAppear block and of course all the labels showed up immediately!  But I still don't know what happened on earth...